# how to make auiManager arbitrary resize and rearrange/sort panes?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to get familiar with auiManager. I need a list of panes with charts which may be resized and rearranged freely and arbitrary. I'm using Row() and Position()  methods of auiPaneInfo class to set the position of the new pane. So, the question is if there is any way to make it resizeble  in two directions? Additionally, is there any way to swap panes or rearrange the positions of the panes? If not, how to implement it?

The example is below (press add menu item to add charts):

```
import wx
import re, math, random
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui
from wx.lib.colourdb import getColourList
class ChartPanel(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent,color="lightgrey"):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._color=color
        self.SetBackgroundColour(self._color)




########################################################################
class ChartFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                        "Chart window: AUI manager",
                        size=(1200,600))
        self._winmgr=aui.AuiManager(agwFlags=aui.AUI_MGR_DEFAULT | aui.AUI_MGR_LIVE_RESIZE)
        self._winmgr.SetManagedWindow(self)
        self._charts={}
        self._n=0
        self._r=-1
        self._c=0

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        chartMenu = wx.Menu()
        addMenuItem = chartMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Add", "Add new chart")
        menuBar.Append(chartMenu, "&Chart")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onChartAdd, addMenuItem)
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self._winmgr.Update()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


    def onChartAdd(self, event):
        self._n = self._n + 1
        if self._r == 3:
            self._r = 0
            self._c = self._c + 1
        else:
            self._r = self._r + 1
        print "r= "+str(self._r)+" c= "+str(self._c)
        p = ChartPanel(self,random.choice(getColourList()))                
        self._charts['p%i'%self._n]=p
        self._winmgr.AddPane(
                self._charts['p%i'%self._n],
                aui.AuiPaneInfo().Caption('Chart %i'%self._n).Center().Position(self._r).Row(self._c).\
                CloseButton(True).MinimizeButton(True).MaximizeButton(True).PinButton(True).\
                BestSize((345, 400))
        )
        self._winmgr.Update()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = ChartFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your sample creates a new column of panes every after every 4th pane and they all resize in both directions for me - wxPython 3.0.1 classic.

Comment: The user can rearrange by dragging the caption bar of a pane, or are you looking for a programmatic way or rearranging?

Comment: Ok, thank you. It seems that for me it doesn't work. I have wxPython 2.8 and suse linux

Comment: wxPython 2.8 is very .... very old, can't you update to 3.0.1 or better 3.0.2?